# Helm select specific field from map

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a values.yaml that looks like this, and I want to select the first url

```
ingress:
  hosts:
    - host: url
      paths:
        - /
    - host: url2
      paths:
        - /
```

Here is what I have currently tried:

{{ first .Values.ingress.hosts.host }}

But I'm getting error:
can't evaluate field host in type interface {}

Could anyone help me format the selection properly to just select the first url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Values.ingress.hosts` is a list, so you have to select the `first` item from that, and then you can select the `host` out of it:

```
{{ (first .Values.ingress.hosts).host }}
```

You could also use the Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) `index` function to do the traversal (where index 0 is "the first item")

```
{{ index .Values.ingress.hosts 0 "host" }}
```